# NodeJS , gulp , Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, gulp

i am working with NodeJS and i am using gulp.

My foler look like that :

```
Root 
  dist
  node_modules
  src
    index.html
  gulpfile.js
  package.json
```

My gulpfile is :

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect'); // runs a local dev server 
var open = require('gulp-open'); // open a URL in a web browser

var config ={
    port : 3000,
    devBaseUrl : 'http://localhost',
    paths:{
        html:'./src/*.html',
        dist:'./dist'
    }
}

//Start a local development server 
gulp.task = ('connect' , function(){
    connect.server({
        root:['dist'],
        port: config.port,
        base: config.devBaseUrl,
    }); 
});

gulp.task('open', ['connect'], function(){
    gulp.src('dist/index.html').pipe(open({uri: config.devBaseUrl + ":" + config.port + '/'}))
});

gulp.task('html',function(){
    gulp.src(config.paths.html)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('default', ['html', 'open']);
```

When i am type 'gulp' in the cmd i get this error :

```
C:\Users\maor\Documents\NodeProject\2>gulp
[13:18:28] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\NodeProject\2\gulpfile.js
[13:18:28] Server started http://localhost:3000
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1262:14)
    at listen (net.js:1298:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1394:5)
    at ConnectApp.server (C:\Users\maor\Documents\NodeProject\2\node_modules\gulp-connect\index.js:57:19)
    at new ConnectApp (C:\Users\maor\Documents\NodeProject\2\node_modules\gulp-connect\index.js:37:10)
    at Object.server (C:\Users\maor\Documents\NodeProject\2\node_modules\gulp-connect\index.js:170:12)
    at Gulp.gulp.task (C:\Users\maor\Documents\NodeProject\2\gulpfile.js:18:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\maor\Documents\NodeProject\2\gulpfile.js:29:6)
```

I really dont know what the problem is , i already checked and the port : 3000 is free. can you guys help me figure what the problem is ?

Answer (score 7):

Are you running any other applications that might be using port 3000?

It's possible that a previous instance of node may still be running, even if you intended to kill it. Check your processes, I sometimes get this issue and generally use

```
killall node
```

to resolve it.

Comment: You might need to add `-KILL`: `killall -KILL node`.

Answer (score 4):

This problem arise, when node process already running on the port.

You can fix it by

pkill node

OR you can use this

killall node

you still see node process with this command: ps aux | grep node.

If you are using windows, then open task manager & in process tab, search node & right click on that process & end process.

Surely it will work.

Comment: C:\> tasklist // will show the list of running process'

      ` Image Name        PID Session Name    Session#    Mem Usage
      System            4   console                 0   236 K`
  ...
  node.exe         3592 console

Comment: Note the PID corresponding to your node process, in this case 3592. Next run taskkill to terminate the process. C:\> taskkill /F /PID 3592

Comment: there is no node process.. i checked it 3 times. there is naother option ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138733/discussion-between-bhaurao-birajdar-and-tal).

Answer (score 4):

Or better still you can change the port number to something else like 8000.